# createLBPHFaceRecognizer() module not found in raspberry pi opencv 2.4.1 and python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I m trying to develop a face recognition system in raspberry pi so i downloaded opencv for python using "apt-get python-opencv" it downloded opencv 2.4.1 and now when i m using "recogniser=createLBPHFaceRecogniser()" it is showing error.

"Traceback(most recent call last):

File "", line 1, n

recogniser=createLBPHFaceRecogniser()

NameError: name 'createLBPHFaceRecogniser()' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you did not import cv2?

```
import cv2

recogniser = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

Also it looks like you have a typo in function name. (createLBPHFaceRecogni**s**er instead of createLBPHFaceRecogni**z**er)

Comment: i did..i importes cv2... actually the same code is working great in macbook with opencv 2.4.12 but not in raspberrypi i think it may be because of older version of opencv(2.4.1) may be it doesn't have that module. but i need a second opinion may be i m wrong somehow.

Comment: and the typo is in this question in actual code i have written 'Recognizer'

Comment: It could be that the binary provided with the apt-get repository was not compiled the module you need to use this function

I have compiled opencv2 from source code using this article an the function is available:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/

It is a little bit long, but detailed and provides step by step guide

Answer (score 0):

try using For on opencv3.3.0

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```